# how to Compare two LIST's

Tags: list, salesforce

I am using two LIST in my code :

```
List<Intake_Details__c> Intake_detailNmbr = [SELECT name FROM Intake_Details__c]; 

List<Claim__c> Claim_detailNmbr = [SELECT name FROM Claim__c];
```

I want to check if any of the values in one list matches with the other list.
Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: You want to see if name is in any of those?